# Difference between get_site_transient() and get_transient()

Tags: transient

I'm reading through the WordPress core and noticed that the *update_core* transient is fetched with `get_site_transient()`.

What is the difference between `get_site_transient()` and `get_transient()`?

If I had seen this somewhere else, I'd have thought: "*well... this is to get a transient for a specific site in multisite.*"

But if this is used for *update_core*, that thought does not make sense, since the core is one ond only one, even in a multisite.

Did I read the [official documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_site_transient/)?

Of course, but it doesn't really clarify it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get_site_transient()` uses the older nomenclature for multisite which referred to a multisite network as a "site" and individual sites on the network as "blogs". So `get_site_transient()` is getting the value of a transient for the whole network, while `get_transient()` gets a transient for an individual site/blog.

If you look at the source of the function you'll see that it uses [`get_site_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_site_option/) internally, and the documentation for that function reads (emphasis mine):

> Retrieve an option value for **the current network** based on name of
> option.

Also note that `get_site_option()` has been effectively replaced with `get_network_option()`, but for some reason the same change hasn't been made for the transient function.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, makes sense.